# JAVA TextArea Wait for Input

Tags: java, javafx

I have a tictactoe game based on two text areas (ta1 is for input (marker location), ta2 is for grid output). player_input() does not work since it takes text from ta1 which is empty. How can to make ta1 wait for input and ENTER press then return location? The whole program crashes because of this I believe.

```
import extendsFX.BaseApps;
import extendsFX.BaseConsole;
import extendsFX.BaseGraphics;
import static extendsFX.BaseApps.nL;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

public class tictactoe extends BaseConsole{

    void display_board(char[] board){
        ta2.appendText("   |   |   " +nL);
        ta2.appendText(" " + board[7] + " | " + board[8] + " | " + board[9] + " "+nL);
        ta2.appendText("   |   |   "+nL);
        ta2.appendText("-----------"+nL);
        ta2.appendText("   |   |   "+nL);
        ta2.appendText(" " + board[4] + " | " + board[5] + " | " + board[6] + " "+nL);
        ta2.appendText("   |   |   "+nL);
        ta2.appendText("-----------"+nL);
        ta2.appendText("   |   |   "+nL);
        ta2.appendText(" " + board[1] + " | " + board[2] + " | " + board[3] + " "+nL);
        ta2.appendText("   |   |   "+nL);
    }

    boolean is_over(char[] board){
        if (board[1] == board[2] && board[2] == board[3] && board[1] != ' ' && board[2] != ' ' && board[3] != ' ')
            return true;
        else if(board[4] == board[5] && board[5] == board[6] && board[4] != ' ' && board[5] != ' ' && board[6] != ' ')
            return true;
        else if(board[7] == board[8] && board[8] == board[9] && board[7] != ' ' && board[8] != ' ' && board[9] != ' ')
            return true;
        else if(board[1] == board[4] && board[4] == board[7] && board[1] != ' ' && board[4] != ' ' && board[7] != ' ')
            return true;
        else if(board[2] == board[5] && board[5] == board[8] && board[2] != ' ' && board[5] != ' ' && board[8] != ' ')
            return true;
        else if(board[3] == board[6] && board[6] == board[9] && board[3] != ' ' && board[6] != ' ' && board[9] != ' ')
            return true;
        else if(board[1] == board[5] && board[5] == board[9] && board[1] != ' ' && board[5] != ' ' && board[9] != ' ')
            return true;
        else if(board[3] == board[5] && board[5] == board[7] && board[3] != ' ' && board[5] != ' ' && board[7] != ' ')
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    void place_marker(char[] board, char marker, int position){
        if (board[position] == ' ')
            board[position] = marker;
        else
            ta2.appendText("Position is already taken! Please choose another spot"+nL);
            while(true) {
                int loc = player_input();
                if (board[loc] == ' ')
                {
                    board[loc] = marker;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }

    int player_input(){
        ta2.appendText("Location: " + nL);
        int location = Integer.parseInt(ta1.getText());
        return location;
    }

    boolean is_full(char[] board){
        for(int n = 1; n < 10; n++){
            if (board[n] == ' ')
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    boolean check_for_draw(char[] board){
        if(is_over(board) == false && is_full(board) == true){
            ta2.appendText("Draw!"+nL);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    char[] board = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};
    char[] board_test = {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'};

//    public void TextArea1KeyPressed(KeyEvent evt, int input1)
//    {
//        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
//            {
//                input1 = player_input();
//            }
//    }

    @Override
    public void createControls() {

        super.createControls()
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("TicTacToe");
        super.start(stage);
        //display_board(board_test);

        while(true){
            //Player1 turn
            ta2.appendText("Player1's turn:"+nL);
            int input1 = 0;

            place_marker(board, 'X', input1);
            ta2.clear();
            display_board(board);
            if (is_over(board) == true){
                ta2.appendText("Player 1 won!"+nL);
                break;
            }
            if(check_for_draw(board) == true)
                break;

            //Player2 turn
            ta2.appendText("Player2's turn:"+nL);
            int input2 = player_input();
            place_marker(board, 'O', input2);
            ta2.clear();
            display_board(board);
            if (is_over(board) == true){
                ta2.appendText("Player 2 won!"+nL);
                break;
            }
            if(check_for_draw(board) == true)
                break;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();

    }
}
```

Comment: related: you want to read up on concurrency in javafx - the info page of the javafx tag has references to basic tutorials

Comment: You are also mixing AWT and JavaFX libraries...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough example of one way to handle your problem. First thing, your `displayBoard()` methods is going to throw an `IndexOutOfBounds` error. I am guessing your board size is 9 and that makes `board[9]` out of bounds. Remember `Arrays` in `Java` are zero-based indexed. This means the last index is the array size - 1. Back to the problem -> This program allows users to enter a number and press enter. It then uses that number to put the `X` or `O` on the board at that location. Remember `Arrays` are zero-base indexed so if you want the user to be able to enter a number from 1 to 9, the program must subtract 1 from each number entered. The `Listener` in this code is problably what you need to address your problem. It listens to what is typed in the input `TextArea`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication374 extends Application
{
    TextArea taInput = new TextArea();
    TextArea taBoard = new TextArea();
    char[] currentBoardState = new char[9];
    char turn;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        taBoard.setEditable(false);//Don't allow user to alter board
        turn = 'X';//Set who is going first X or O.

        //Set all the character to empty space.
        for (int i = 0; i < currentBoardState.length; i++) {
            currentBoardState[i] = ' ';
        }

        displayBoard(currentBoardState);//Display initial board.

        VBox root = new VBox(taInput, taBoard);//Add input and board to the scene.

        //Use listener to update board state
        taInput.setOnKeyReleased((event) -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                String[] tempInput = taInput.getText().split("\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < tempInput.length; i++) {
                    currentBoardState[Integer.parseInt(tempInput[i]) - 1] = turn;//Change the 0 based array to a 1 based array.
                    //Switch turn to other player
                    if (turn == 'X') {
                        turn = 'O';
                    }
                    else {
                        turn = 'X';
                    }
                }

                displayBoard(currentBoardState);//display board after update.
            }
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void displayBoard(char[] board)
    {
        StringBuilder boardString = new StringBuilder();
        boardString.append(board[6]).append(" | ").append(board[7]).append(" | ").append(board[8]).append(System.lineSeparator())
                .append("----------").append(System.lineSeparator())
                .append(board[3]).append(" | ").append(board[4]).append(" | ").append(board[5]).append(System.lineSeparator())
                .append("----------").append(System.lineSeparator())
                .append(board[0]).append(" | ").append(board[1]).append(" | ").append(board[2]).append(System.lineSeparator());

        taBoard.setText(boardString.toString());
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]
The board is kinda off but I was not shooting for perfection. This is more about coding ideas.

Comment: It would be preferable to use `taInput.getParagraphs()` instead of `taInput.getText().split("\n")`. Just don't get any ideas and cast an element ot the list to `StringBuilder` ;) also you could rewrite the turn changing to `turn = 'X' - turn +'O';` :P

Comment: @fabian, thanks for the coding advice. From someone who loves math, the turn code is interesting. I would have never thought to do it that way. Using `getParagrapsh()`, I kept running into problems. I didn't know `getParagrapsh()` existed. I was able to eventually get it to work but I am unsure about the code.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure why this would go wrong. Afaik from what I can tell from looking at the source code the `paragraphs` list contains `StringBuilder`s that are internally used to seperate the lines, but I may be wrong. The property is not exactly well documented (or sufficiently hidden from the user to not mess up the internals when modifying the contents of one of those `StringBuilder`s).

Comment: Most likely has nothing to do with your ideas and everything to do with my implementation.